# Using ".." in custom data attribute selector

Tags: javascript, html, href, custom-data-attribute

I ran across some code that looks like this:

```
<a href="#" data-target=".. .. .. .class-name">
```

I've never seen sets of dots used to target CSS classes. It is used to select that class, and feed data into it, but if I remove the dots, it can't find the class anymore to insert the data. Is this something the original developer built in? Or is this a standard CSS selector? How does these dots work?

Comment: What does the corresponding markup look like?

Comment: Its not CSS its a custom string in a custom "data" attribute (so what it *actually* does will depend upon the script that uses it)

Comment: Without seeing the actual code that uses this data, it's really impossible to say *anything* about it. Other than `.class-name`, nothing here makes any sense as a CSS selector.

Comment: @AlexK. That's what I was afraid of, I couldn't find anything anywhere about any kind of CSS selector using series of dots.

Comment: @paulRoub I unfortunately don't have access to that code, and the developer is out of touch now. I didn't think it made sense as a CSS selector, thanks.

Comment: It's not CSS. It's a data attribute.